# Abnormal behavior to show loading processor

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, loading, deferred

Maybe I should refine my example.

```js
    function doSomethingHeavy() {
        // emulate do something heavy
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < now + 5000) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    $("#testButton").bind("click.performTest", function () {
        $("#loading").show();
        doSomethingHeavy();
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="testButton">Perform Test</button>
<div id="loading" style="display:none" >Loading</div>
```

I assumed the show loading is called then doSomethingHeavy, after that hide the loading. But, the loading is shown and hide after all are done...

Comment: do you really expect to use Deferred in your solution or can i offer an alternative solution?

Comment: A browser won't repaint until your Javascript finishes.  You can't loop like this and expect a repaint during that.  Javascript does not work that way.  Since you are using jQuery, you can just use jQuery animations and delays or a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Also, why use promises for a synchronous operation?  Odd.

Comment: I would like to ask "Why" but not "How". Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have refined my example. I would like to ask why the loading is not shown before doSomethingHeavy() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @jfriend00 should work. But using `window.setTimeout` is unreliable. Just checked using a VM with slow CPU/ low memory, `window.setTimeout` with 15ms is not working...

For a more reliable way to do, you can try to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` which can guarantee the redraw/ reflow event occurred.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showLoading() {
        $("#loading").show();
    }

    function hideLoading() {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }

    function performTest() {
        showLoading();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            // redraw/ reflow occurred for #loading to show...
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                doSomethingHeavy(4000);
                hideLoading();
            });
        });
    }

    function doSomethingHeavy(processTime) {
        // emulate do something heavy
        var start = +new Date();
        while (+new Date() - start < processTime) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    $("#testButton").bind("click.performTest", performTest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="testButton">Perform Test</button>
<div id="loading" style="display: none">Loading... (this will disappear in 4 seconds)</div>
```

Use nested `window.requestAnimationFrame` to wrap `doSomethingHeavy` is odd and not intuitive, maybe worth to use promise pattern...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showLoading() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            $("#loading").show();
            // ensure the redraw/ reflow occurred, then resolve the callback
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function hideLoading() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
            // ensure the redraw/ reflow occurred, then resolve the callback
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function performTest() {
        $.when(showLoading()).then(function () {
            doSomethingHeavy(4000);
        }).done(hideLoading);
    }

    function doSomethingHeavy(processTime) {
        // emulate do something heavy
        var start = +new Date();
        while (+new Date() - start < processTime) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    $("#testButton").bind("click.performTest", performTest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="testButton">Perform Test</button>
<div id="loading" style="display: none">Loading... (this will disappear in 4 seconds)</div>
```

Comment: Seems this is most reliable solution. 
As requestAnimationFrame not cross browser. Finally I imported a library "request-frame" to make requestAnimationFrame cross browser. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `apply` function, which holds the execution thread for 5 seconds.

In javascript, both script execution and ui refreshing happens in a single thread, so if you are running a script until it is finished the UI will not get updated.

So your `apply` function is holding the execution thread soon after the show is called thus the display of the element in the UI is not executed.

So to delay the execution of an item, instead of using a hard coded `while` loop based delay use a timer as shown below.

```js
function show() {
  return $("#loading").show().promise();
}

function hide() {
  return $("#loading").hide().promise();
}

function start() {
  return $.when(show()).then(apply).then(hide);
}

function apply() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 5000)
  return deferred.promise();
}

start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading" style="display:none">Loading</div>
```

---

But a jQuery-ish solution is as simple as

```js
function start() {
  return $("#loading").show().delay(5000).hide(0);
}

start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading" style="display:none">Loading</div>
```

Comment: Actually I do not want to delay but do something very heavy (time consuming). I have refined my example that without any promise pattern. The problem still not solved. Maybe, it is related to what you say "In javascript, both script execution and ui refreshing happens in a single thread, so if you are running a script until it is finished the UI will not get updated."

Comment: then you can just put the time consuming activity in a `setTimeout(function(){}, 0)` handler

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function.

Here's an example using it:

```js
var DELAY = 1000,
  ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;

var loading = {
  elm: function() {
    return $('#loading').delay(DELAY);
  },
  show: function() {
    loading.elm().fadeIn(ANIMATION_DURATION);
  },
  hide: function() {
    loading.elm().fadeOut(ANIMATION_DURATION);
  }
};

loading.show();

setTimeout(loading.hide, 2000);
```

```css
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```